# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I know is simple but i don't know at this moment

In my controller i use

```
$result = DB::select("SELECT name FROM account_name WHERE name='".$name."'");
```

I can't get the data out from that array

`dd($result)` show me:

```
array:1 [
  0 => {#232
    +"name": "John"
  }
]
```

How to get that John out????

I have tried `$result[0]["name"]` but no success and give me that error

Comment: `$result[0]->name`

Comment: simple and efficient :D thx

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = DB::table('account_name')->select('name')->where('name', $name)->first();
```

Then:

```
$result->name; // John
```

Or you can do:

```
$result = DB::table('account_name')->where('name', $name)->value('name');
```

Then:

```
$result; // John
```

Comment: Aren't the results with `get` an array (or strictly said - collection)? Shouldn't you use `first()` instead?

Comment: it is working ok :D thank you $result = DB::table('account_name')->where('name', $name)->value('name');

Answer (score 1):

You can cast object to array like that `(array) $object`.

You can also check if it's an object : `if(is_object($variable)) $variable = (array) $variable`

Comment: plus points for type casting. i often find myself completely forgetting type casting even exists because php doesn't require it.